# Taking vector size() out of loop condition to optimize

Tags: c++

fibs is a std::vector. Using g++, I was advised to take fibs.size() out of the loop, to save computing it each time (because the vector could change)

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < fibs.size(); ++i){
    if(fibs[i] % 2 == 0){
        sum += fibs[i];
    }
}
```

Surely there is some dataflow analysis in the compiler that would tell us that fibs won't change size. Is there? Or should I set some other variable to be fibs.size() and use that in the loop condition?

Comment: 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + ... + F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n+2</sub> - 1.

Comment: So whoever advised you doesn't want the `size` to be computed each time (a subtraction in g++, prior to optimization), but doesn't mind calling `operator[]` (and extra addition compared with using an iterator, prior to optimization) twice. What, and indeed ever. It would be better to either look at the emitted instructions, or time it.

Comment: Steve, If i know that the size of the vector is guaranteed not to change, wouldn't it just save time to use operator[]?

Also, I'm a c++ clown. So is using an iterator is faster?

Comment: @Steve, are you just suggesting that is better to use an iterator? Or that in this case there is a better alternative to operator[]?

Comment: @shuttle87: I'm saying that *if* someone (whoever gave this advice) is going to make wild generalities about performance, I'm a little surprised that they're guessing `size()` is slower than accessing a variable, but they aren't guessing that `operator[]` is slower than using an iterator or pointer. I wouldn't guess exactly what the optimizer will do - it might actually manage to replace the index `i` with a pointer, but to do so it must somehow convince itself that the vector never reallocates, which is hardly any easier than convincing itself it can hoist the value of `size`.

Comment: The basic issue is that `operator[]` will have to load the vector's base pointer out of the vector object (and add the index), just like `size()` on gcc loads the base and end pointers out of the vector object (and subtract them). So it's pretty much the same kind of fiddly micro-optimization in both cases. Personally I'd worry about neither of them until this code is a proven bottleneck, then inspect the emitted code. But if you're going to worry about one I think you should worry about both.

Comment: I completely agree with Steve: you should get used to iterators for their semantics not for performance, and you should be very careful with the advice you received, if they gave the advice just looking at the code, that it is flawed, as there might be higher costs somewhere else. If they gave the advice based on the generated code, then you have missed the most important bit: understanding why *in this particular case* you should prefer to use one over the other: analysis of the generated code.

Comment: @Steve, agree that this should be an iterator or a pointer if the aim is performance. I can't see how putting the size outside of the loop cannot be worse than it being it the loop though. While worrying about these micro optimizations is usually not worth the time, the question seems to be specifically about how the compiler deals with one of these micro optimizations. It might be interesting to see a comparison of the performance of the optimized code here, something I'll do soon when I have some time.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler will likely determine that it won't change. Even if it did, `size()` for vectors is an O(1) operation.

Comment: O(1) only says that it's bounded. It's still may be costly (well, not for a vector).

Answer (score 5):

Unless you know it's a problem, leave it as it is. First make it correct, then make it clear, then make it fast (if necessary).

`vector::size` is extremely fast anyway. It seems to me likely that the compiler will optimise this case, since it is fairly obvious that the vector is not modified and all the functions called will be inlined so the compiler can tell.

You could always look at the generated code to see if this has happened.

If you do want to change it, you need to be able to measure the time it takes before and after. That's a fair amount of work - you probably have better things to do.

Answer (score 3):

size() is constant time operation, there's no penalty calling it this way. If you are concerned about performance and a more general way to go through the collection, use iterators:

```
int sum = 0;
for(auto it = fibs.cbegin(); it != fibs.cend(); ++it) {
    if((*it) % 2 == 0){
        sum += *it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing another, more important point here: Is this loop causing a slow-down of your application? If you do not know for sure (i.e. if you haven't profiled), you risk focusing on the wrong parts of your application.

You already have to keep thousands of things in your head when writing programs (coding guidelines, architecture (bigger picture) of your application, variable names, function names, class names, readability, etc.), you can ignore the speed of the code during your initial implementation (in at least 95% of the time). This will allow you to focus on things, which are more important and far more valuable (like correctness, readability and maintainability).

Answer (score 1):

In your example the compiler can easily analyze the flow and determine that it doesn't change. In more complicated code it cannot:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fibs.size(); ++i){
    complicated_function();
}
```

`complicated_function` can change `fibs`. However, since the above code involves a function call, the compiler cannot store `fibs.size()` in a register and hence you cannot eliminate the memory access.